# Access SQL Server 2000 from Win2008 x64

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit

I just tried installing the SQL Server 2000 client tools on a new Win2008 R2 server (being used for development and testing) using the "standard" install CD. It can't proceed because SQL 2000 isn't supported.

I don't want to install the server, just the client tools (Enterprise Manager and Query Analyser). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to and manage SQL 2000 using SQL Management Studio which ships with SQL 2005 and 2008.  You can also [download SQL Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en) free from Microsoft.

Comment: I've installed SQL2008 and it looks like I can access/explore the DTS jobs setup on the SQL2000 server too (although I need to install some backward compatibility feature from SQL2005 first but my question here has been answered). Thanks